# Accessing associative array element using another element in PHP

Tags: php

I'm quite new to PHP and I'm not really sure how to ask this question. My data is like this (displayed in JSON for easy viewing but i actually use array)

```
[{"_id":"1","title":"Month & Year","description":"To be used in Jurisprudence"},
 {"_id":"3","title":"Bible Version I","description":"Testament - Book - Chapter"}]
```

I know in PHP that i can access elements of associative array by using foreach as well as using the standard for loop.

e.g:

```
for($n=0;$n<sizeof($array_data);$n++){
     echo $array_data[$n]['title'];
}
```

Instead of using the index, what i want to do if possible is to access title using the _id. Something like, if have 3 as _id it should display the corresponding title in that array which is Bible Version I.

Comment: You have the tag `associative-array`, but your array is not associative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `if` statement.

```
foreach ($array_data as $item) {
    if ($item['_id'] == 3) {
        echo $item['title'];
        break;
    }
}
```

If you'll be doing this a lot, you should probably change your array to an associative array, so you can then just use `$array_data[3]`. E.g. it should be:

```
{
    "1": {"_id":"1","title":"Month & Year","description":"To be used in Jurisprudence"},
    "3": {"_id":"3","title":"Bible Version I","description":"Testament - Book - Chapter"}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But can i do it without using a loop? The thing is, i'm saving the _id as value in an html element. Since i have the array already loaded in the browser i just want to call the particular title via the _id saved. I already used the loop for loading the data in the html elements thus i dont want to iterate again using another one.

Comment: No, you can't do it without a loop unless you change the array to an associative array first.

Comment: @ReubenJaMesAveñoGruta whatever you do, you need to loop. If you're searching an array, you have no choice

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer! Just upvoted your answer, I just have another question if you don't mind. Lets say my data is thousands or even millions. If i use loop several times just to look for data in the web page itself (data already sent by the controller to the view) will my server be affected by that heavy activity or my end user?

Comment: Looping every time will be expensive. That's why you should use the associative array, accessing these elements is very efficient. If you have that many items you should probably be using a database.

Comment: Thanks again for that info! Since you bought up the usage of associative array do you think this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php is sufficient for what i need? I actually fetched the data provided earlier from mysql database but not as an associative array.

Comment: No. I'm talking about the outer array being associative, `mysql_fetch_assoc`  creates an associative array for the rows, which you already have.

Comment: I mean you should do a database query like `SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE id = 3`

Comment: Or when you fetch the data fromthe database, you can do `$array_data[$row['_id']] = $row;` to create an associative array from the table.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't be using the obsolete `mysql` extension. Use `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient solution without a loop would be to use array_search with array_column :

```
$key = array_search("3", array_column($array_data, '_id'));
if ($myArray[$key]) {
  echo $myArray[$key]['_id'] . ' : ' . $myArray[$key]['title'];
}
```

Uses php 5.5.0 or above. Refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: This is TWO loops, one loop to get all the column values, a second loop to search it for the ID you want.

Comment: The loops are hidden inside the `array_column` and `array_search` functions, but they're still there.

Comment: @Barmar Are you sure ? Can you point to any doc or ref if array_column or array_search are loops ?